# EF Core 3.1 scaffolding in Visual Studio PostgreSQL DB First Approach

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Trying to scaffold a postgresql table  in Visual Studio using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.11. The table has a composite primary key with a varchar and  date field. Getting the following  error.

"Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table"

Any help will be appreciated

Upgraded the package to 5.0.1 and but that did not help.

Comment: is this message in yellow color instead of red ? If it is in yellow,  you can safely ignore them

Comment: @XinranShen EF core is not generating model and db  context changes for the table.